# CKEditor - Change image source

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have made some custom functionality to the CKEditor. In short, it shows a div tag with 5 links, for Small, Medium, Large X-Large and Original size.

When I click the links, it changes the SRC attribute of the image to the correct size.

It works, but it doesn't persist back to the editor. It's like the Image i get through the click event target, is not part of the Source code.

How can I change the Source code, when manipulating with the elements in the editor?

My code looks like this:

```
$(target).ckeditor(function (editor) {
    $(this.document.$).bind("click", function (event) {
        var target = $(event.target);

        if (target.is("img")) {
            var p = $("<div contenteditable='false' class='image-properties'>" + Milkshake.Resources.Text.size + ": <a class='sizeLink' href='#size1Img'>S</a>&nbsp;<a class='sizeLink' href='#size2Img'>M</a>&nbsp;<a class='sizeLink' href='#size3Img'>L</a>&nbsp;<a class='sizeLink' href='#size4Img'>XL</a>&nbsp;<a class='sizeLink' href='#size5Img'>Org.</a></div>");
            p.css("top", target.position().top);

            var regex = new RegExp(/(size\d{1}img)/i);
            var match = regex.exec(target.attr("src"));

            if (match != null) {
                var imgSrize = match[0];
                p.find("a[href=#" + imgSrize + "]").addClass("selected");
            }

            p.delegate("a", "click", function (e) {
                var link = $(e.target);

                if (!link.is(".selected")) {
                    $(".selected", link.parent()).removeClass("selected");
                    link.addClass("selected");

                    var imageSrc = target.attr("src");
                    imageSrc = imageSrc.replace(/(size\d{1}img)/i, link.attr("href").substring(1));

                    target.attr("src", imageSrc);
                    target.css("width", "");
                    target.css("height", "");
                }

                e.preventDefault();
            });

            p.insertAfter(target);
        } else if (!target.is("div.image-properties")) {
            $("div.image-properties", target.parent()).remove();
        }
    });
```

Comment: +1 I like tough CKEditor questions, although I don't know the answer. Maybe @AlfonsoML will see it, he's a CKEditor developer and pretty active here.

Comment: Might be worth trying to `trigger('change')` on the editor, this worked for me in a custom TinyMCE piece I wrote.

Comment: @Madmartigan Didn't work. Damn.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand that jQuery code, but if you use Firebug you'll see that images have their src protected (to avoid all the browser bugs) with something like data-ckeditor-src

Comment: @AlfonsoML - you deserve the points for the correct answer. The attribute was called 'data-cke-saved-src', and now it works. Damn I missed that - but please write your answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `src` of images and `href` of links are protected in CKEditor to avoid browser bugs (when copying, dragging or sometimes even just loading the content), so you must update also this custom attribute:

`data-cke-saved-src`

Comment: is there any way to unprotect the source of the editor when an image is added to it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You can get the HTML by calling editor.getData()

Comment: when you use the file browser to add an image to the content of the wysiwyg it disables the source button so you can no longer view source.  is there anyway to override this?

Comment: No, it doesn't do that and in any way that's totally unrelated to the original question. If you have that problem create your own question and provide as much detail as possible.

Comment: I thought it was related because of your statement "The src of images and href of links are protected in CKEditor to avoid browser bugs" + I did create a question.  thanks for being such an AMAZING HELP.