# In CkEditor 4.3 with Image2 plugin, what is the right way to change the image src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, ckeditor

As the title says, I'm using a version of [CkEditor 4.3](http://ckeditor.com/download), based on the full package, that includes also the [Image2 plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image2) (build with [CkBuilder](http://ckeditor.com/builder), in order to automatically solve every dependency).

What I need is to change programmatically (using, if needed, also jQuery) the `src` attribute of an image.

With the classic [Image plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image), I did this with the following code:

```
var imgToBeReplaced = editor.document.findOne("img#myImg");
imgToBeReplaced.setAttribute("src", newSrc);
```

Because I need to be sure that the getData() method of the editor object returns the right data, I do also the following (read more about it: [CKEditor - Change image source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593296/ckeditor-change-image-source)):

```
$(imgToBeReplaced.$).attr("data-cke-saved-src", newSrc);
```

When I do this with the [Image2 plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/image2), the image is correctly changed, but after that, I cannot resize it and I cannot access to the image properties (neither with double-click on the image, nor using the context menu that opens right-clicking on the image, because the option "properties" is no more present).

So, the question is: how can I correctly change the `src` (and `data-cke-saved-src`) attribute(s), without losing the possibility of changing the image properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now with **widgets** the only things you need to worry about are

- fetching proper widget instance
- calling [`setData()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget-method-setData) method

As for this particular case you need to

```
// You need to have CKEDITOR.editor instance, here i will pick it from instances property.
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1,
    // All widgets instances are stored here, we will iterate on top of them.
    widgets = editor.widgets.instances,
    curWidget,
    i;

for ( i in widgets ) {
    curWidget = widgets[ i ];
    // Ensure that image is a part of widget, and src matchs our needs.
    if ( curWidget.definition.name == 'image2' && curWidget.parts.image.getAttribute( 'src' ) == 'assets/image1.jpg' ) {
        // Update src attribute.
        curWidget.setData( 'src', 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/18/Unicorn-head-circle-2.png' );
    }
}
```

This will be correct way to update **image2** src - all the stuff will be handled by image2 plugin itself.

Comment: Your method is wonderful, but it only works changing `curWidget.definition.name == 'image2'` to `curWidget.definition.name == 'image'` ;) Thank you very much (and, please, make this edit in you answer)

Comment: I'm glad that solution worked for you, however are you sure about definition name? I'm pretty sure that it should be image2. :) Please double check it and let me know.

Comment: VitoShadow is right - the name of the widget has been changed in 4.3.1. We did that to make it easier to replace the old image plugin with image2.

Comment: PS. If you want to modify focused widget, then you can simply this code by using [`editor.widgets.focused`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.repository-property-focused).

Comment: @Reinmar - Quick side question:  Image2 declares a `widget` variable in global scope, then sets `widget` to `this.widget` in the `onShow` function.  I can't recreate this in my own dialog definition.  I `console.log`'d `this` within my dialog's `onShow` method, and it doesn't contain `widget`. Any idea why?

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but perhaps you need this: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/67433b06950bd84f195a0b56db082069384cc455/plugins/image2/plugin.js#L441-L444