# CKEditor is changing my SRC or Href when saving

Tags: ckeditor, dnn9

I am trying to save a link in DotNetNuke (DNN) using the CKEditor for the HTML module.

When I save, the editor will automatically adjust the link.
I am trying to save it as

```
data-src="#bronze"
```

The reason for the hashtag is for displaying a fancybox pop-up with hidden content. https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#inline

But the editor adds /portals/2/ in front of this URL.

[image]
I have looked at this article below.

[CKEditor - Change image source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593296/ckeditor-change-image-source#)

I assume the CKEditor is saving the SRC and Href links in protected mode for browsers. Is there a way that I can turn this off in the settings?

I did try to change to RAW mode, but it still does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I face the same problem on data-fancybox-href, the only solution I can think of is using jQuery / javascript to change back to correct value:

```
var src = $(".more_info_btn")
$.each(src, function(){
  var href = src.attr("data-src")
  var hrefArr = href.split("#")
  href = "#" + hrefArr[hrefArr.length-1]
  $(this).attr("data-src", href)
})
```

Comment: I used JQuery as well to open a hidden DIV programmatically with fancybox.